# Ruby on Rails Application coult not include stylesheet nor js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stylesheet

Im working at a windows 8.1 64bit computer and jetzt succeed in creating a scaffold when i found the next problem ....
these are the commands i executed:

```
rails new obs
cd obs
rails generate scaffold Customer name:string
rake db:migrate
rails s
```

but i cant open the window because of this error:

> TypeError: Das Objekt unterstützt diese Eigenschaft oder Methode nicht.
>   Rails.root: C:/Users/Adrian/Documents/Bumblebee
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__353703031_44962284'

i havent changed anything at the created files. but cant see any problems ...

Comment: What window were you trying to open? What is on the associated line in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb?

Comment: And the error in English?

Comment: i use GoogleChrome to open. and  line 5 & 6 in application.html is the following: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>. The error in English: 'typeerror object doesn't support this property or method'

Comment: just found a way to solve this problem... theres a little programm which i had to install on windows : https://nodejs.org/en/ --- by using this, its possible to write js functions and include stylesheets as like on linux :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the code application to default like this:-

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "default", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "default", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```