# Errors after installing bootstrap-sass on ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-sass

I'm trying to create a webapp with rails and bootstrap-sass.
I installed those with instructions from [Ruby On Rails With Bootstrap Tutorial (simple)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf_Si8_szmM&t=309s), which works.

After installing the bootstrap-sass gem, and trying to open my app in the browser, ruby/rails gets me an error msg.

> Showing C:/Sites/bopp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:
>   TypeError: Das Objekt unterstützt diese Eigenschaft oder Methode nicht.>

Entries:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

According to [Ruby on Rails Application coult not include stylesheet nor js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880659/ruby-on-rails-application-coult-not-include-stylesheet-nor-js) I changed it, and got another error:

> Showing C:/Sites/bopp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:
>   The asset "default.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.

Entries:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "default", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "default", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I changed application.css to application.css.scss.
Entries:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
*
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
```

Only one change in  Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

I changed nothing else.

Then I ran `bundle install`.

Ruby Version: 2.3.3
Rails Version: 5.1.0 (downloaded from http://railsinstaller.org/en)
OS: Windows 7
Editor: Sublime Text 2
Browser: Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Maybe some more info about the first message with 'The object does not support this property or method'. Maybe the name of the file which should be layouts/application.html.erb and specifically what is on line 7?

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly you need to change default to application.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

It is looking for a default.css file but should be looking for your application.css file or your application.js file. By changing your first issue you caused your second one.

Comment: Thx for your answer,
If I change "default" back to "application" (that is the standard entry) I get the first error msg. As I mentioned, I changed it to "default" because I found that in an other answer on this website.
The first error msg is about property and method, and the second is about the asset.css. So, I don't know that to do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I had to remove `//= require_tree .` from `application.js`

There is an answer here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520456/execjsruntimeerror-on-windows-trying-to-follow-rubytutorial)